# Debugging not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I am unable to debug my app in Android Studio. It always keep showing this message

```
Warning: debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse
Restart ADB integration and try again
Waiting for process: com.#######
```

I can't debug by any method neither run time nor launching app in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn it on the Android side? The option is hidden behind a backdoor now.

Then Windows need driver, Linux does not need driver, same might be but I don't know goes to Mac OS X. Windows driver for Nexuses are already included.

Comment: OS X doesn't need more than the driver included in the SDK Manager too

Answer (score 0):

This method that I'm writing it works for windows :

1-You need to get your device's drivers using the manufacturer's website. (ADB Drivers).This is a must for debugging and it seems that it is where your problem is lying beneath. If you use a simulator like Genymotion, skip this step.
2-Enable USB debugging from developer options.
3-Connect your device.

Comment: device is shown connected for few seconds and then it goes again and this process goes on and on

Comment: @VivekMishra Can you normally transfer files without the device being disconnected? Or the disconnection happens only when debugging?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message is displaying
Warning: debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse

You have Eclipse program running which is using the ADB Connection. So first close the Eclipse Program and Try Debugging in Android Studio, if problem persist then restart Android Studio or restart machine